# How to open links in vscode without mouse and click?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, hotkeys

By default to open link in vscode (for example it might be functions) used *Left Click + command*

How i can bind this for hotkey without mouse?

i tried editor.action.openLink hotkey, but i still need to point my mouse in link.

Comment: Do you want to be able to open a link on the screen in vscode without hovering over it? That would immediately fall apart with more than one link and thus there is not a way to do so, without making an extension. Are you trying to say that you still have to click?

Comment: @MrDiamond i wanna make it without click if its possible

Comment: Sadly it is not possible without an extension in this case.

Comment: @MrDiamond can you recommend some of extensions?

Comment: I do not know of any, most likely you will have to code it yourself since this is a pretty specific problem.